# how to iterate correct over rows and cells in xlsx

Tags: java, loops, apache-poi, xlsx

i'm not sure, maybe we had an similar request here and i'm to stupid to find the right request.

My English is not so  good, i hope i can explain what i need. I have the Task, to iterate through an xlsx File, which contains information about one Sprint and absence of our teamcollegues.

I need help for the iteration, i'm a noob and i try it with 'for loop' but it confused me totally.

Here is what i have now:

```
public void go() throws Exception, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(25);

    Row ersteReihe = sheet.getRow(0);
    Cell datum1 = ersteReihe.getCell(1);  //Date in column B1


    System.out.println("\n\nAbwesenheit " +sheet.getSheetName() );

    // Hole aus der zweiten Reihe den ersten Namen:
    Row zweiteReihe = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell name1 = zweiteReihe.getCell(0);     //Name of employee
    Cell isDa1 = zweiteReihe.getCell(1);     //Information with 1 and 0 who is absence
    int zell1 = (int) isDa1.getNumericCellValue();
    if (zell1 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + name1.getStringCellValue() + " ist am " + datum1 + " nicht Anwesend ");
    }
    // Hole aus der zweiten Reihe den ersten Namen:
    Row dritteReihe = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell name2 = dritteReihe.getCell(0);
    Cell isDa2 = dritteReihe.getCell(1);
    int zell2 = (int) isDa2.getNumericCellValue();
    if (zell2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + name2.getStringCellValue() + " ist am " + datum1 + " nicht Anwesend ");
    }
    // Hole aus der zweiten Reihe den ersten Namen:
    Row vierteReihe = sheet.getRow(3);
    Cell name3 = vierteReihe.getCell(0);
    Cell isDa3 = vierteReihe.getCell(1);
    int zell3 = (int) isDa3.getNumericCellValue();
    if (zell3 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + name3.getStringCellValue() + " ist am " + datum1 + " nicht Anwesend ");
    }
    // Hole aus der zweiten Reihe den ersten Namen:
    Row fuenfteReihe = sheet.getRow(4);
    Cell name4 = fuenfteReihe.getCell(0);
    Cell isDa4 = fuenfteReihe.getCell(1);
    int zell4 = (int) isDa4.getNumericCellValue();
    if (zell4 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + name4.getStringCellValue() + " ist am " + datum1 + " nicht Anwesend ");
    }
    // Hole aus der zweiten Reihe den ersten Namen:
    Row sechsteReihe = sheet.getRow(5);
    Cell name5 = sechsteReihe.getCell(0);
    Cell isDa5 = zweiteReihe.getCell(1);
    int zell5 = (int) isDa5.getNumericCellValue();
    if (zell5 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + name5.getStringCellValue() + " ist am " + datum1 + " nicht Anwesend ");
    }
    // Hole aus der zweiten Reihe den ersten Namen:
    Row siebteReihe = sheet.getRow(6);
    Cell name6 = siebteReihe.getCell(0);
    Cell isDa6 = siebteReihe.getCell(1);
    int zell6 = (int) isDa6.getNumericCellValue();
    if (zell6 == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + name6.getStringCellValue() + " ist am " + datum1 + " nicht Anwesend ");
    }

    fis.close();

}
```

I going to be crazy. cause i'm not able to find the right solution for an correct iteration :(

Could someone help me please? Please be lenient with me :)

Thanks a lot!
Cheers Adissa

Answer (score 2):

Since Sheets and Rows are Iterables, iterating over rows and cells is very easy:

```
Sheet sheet = ...
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        // Actual work on cell here
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, i dont now how it works here...i have done it with the for loop, and i'm getting a nullpointerException after the last row, so i think i have to use something like Row.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK?